# What permission do I need on Azure AD application to read a folder in ShraePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I have an app registered in Azure AD with the following approved permissions:

Microsoft Graph: Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All, Sites.Selected, User.Read
and
SharePoint: Sites.ReadWrite.All, Sites.Selected

Yet a request to load a folder at / fails with 403 Forbidden (the same C# application that uses a different, registered earlier, Azure AD application works fine - I just can't figure out what the differences are, and how to get second app's permissions to work like the first app does).

Which permissions do I need to read a folder?

Are there logs that can give me more information?

[image]

Comment: Which API endpoint are you calling?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on which authentication flow you use, because you are only granting application permissions, which are only supported in the client credentials flow. So if you're using the **client credentials flow**, your permissions are sufficient. However, if you are using **auth code flow** or **ROPC flow**, you also need to grant `Files.ReadWrite.All` and `Sites.ReadWrite.All` **delegated permissions**.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, I needed `Sites.Selected` permission (which I did). However, I had to use the PowerShell PnP module to explicitly grant `write` permission to my app for each site I need to access. From what I figured out as of today there is no GUI way to do that configuration (I suspect sites could have been configured when the application's permission request was initially granted, but I am not the one who approved those requests).